# NextJS project failing to build

Tags: next.js

I am using the newly launched `app` router in one of my project. But the project is getting the following errors during it's build but working fine on the dev server.

My Build Logs are as follows:

```
[16:48:54.402] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[16:48:54.472] Cloning github.com/...../video-streamer (Branch: master, Commit: f21789d)
[16:48:54.776] Previous build cache not available
[16:48:54.877] Cloning completed: 404.594ms
[16:48:55.235] Running "vercel build"
[16:48:55.746] Vercel CLI 31.2.3
[16:48:55.999] Installing dependencies...
[16:49:06.951] 
[16:49:06.951] added 435 packages in 11s
[16:49:06.951] 
[16:49:06.952] 148 packages are looking for funding
[16:49:06.952]   run `npm fund` for details
[16:49:06.977] Detected Next.js version: 13.4.13
[16:49:06.981] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[16:49:06.981] Running "npm run build"
[16:49:07.282] 
[16:49:07.283] > videostreamer@0.1.0 build
[16:49:07.283] > next build
[16:49:07.283] 
[16:49:08.108] - warn You have enabled experimental feature (serverActions) in next.config.js.
[16:49:08.108] - warn Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
[16:49:08.109] 
[16:49:08.125] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[16:49:08.125] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[16:49:08.125] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[16:49:08.125] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[16:49:08.125] 
[16:49:08.217] - info Creating an optimized production build...
[16:49:12.735] Failed to compile.
[16:49:12.736] 
[16:49:12.736] HookWebpackError: Class constructor URL cannot be invoked without 'new'
[16:49:12.737]     at makeWebpackError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:311138)
[16:49:12.737]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:105977
[16:49:12.737]     at eval (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:47:1)
[16:49:12.737]     at callback (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:69384)
[16:49:12.737]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/src/build/webpack/plugins/next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.ts:664:31
[16:49:12.737]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[16:49:12.738] -- inner error --
[16:49:12.738] TypeError: Class constructor URL cannot be invoked without 'new'
[16:49:12.738]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[16:49:12.738] caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
[16:49:12.738] TypeError: Class constructor URL cannot be invoked without 'new'
[16:49:12.739]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[16:49:12.739] 
[16:49:12.739] HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')
[16:49:12.739]     at makeWebpackError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:311138)
[16:49:12.739]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:105977
[16:49:12.739]     at eval (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:13:1)
[16:49:12.739]     at fn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:69078)
[16:49:12.739]     at _next6 (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:11:1)
[16:49:12.739]     at eval (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:27:1)
[16:49:12.739]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[16:49:12.739] -- inner error --
[16:49:12.739] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')
[16:49:12.740]     at FlightClientEntryPlugin.createActionAssets (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/src/build/webpack/plugins/flight-client-entry-plugin.ts:873:48)
[16:49:12.740]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/src/build/webpack/plugins/flight-client-entry-plugin.ts:236:26
[16:49:12.740]     at fn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:69057)
[16:49:12.740]     at _next6 (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:11:1)
[16:49:12.740]     at eval (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:27:1)
[16:49:12.740]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[16:49:12.740] caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
[16:49:12.740] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')
[16:49:12.741]     at FlightClientEntryPlugin.createActionAssets (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/src/build/webpack/plugins/flight-client-entry-plugin.ts:873:48)
[16:49:12.741]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/src/build/webpack/plugins/flight-client-entry-plugin.ts:236:26
[16:49:12.741]     at fn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:69057)
[16:49:12.741]     at _next6 (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:11:1)
[16:49:12.741]     at eval (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:27:1)
[16:49:12.741]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[16:49:12.741] 
[16:49:12.742] 
[16:49:12.742] > Build failed because of webpack errors
[16:49:12.778] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I am using `Next v13.4.13`

Kindly help me getting out of it.

Thanks in advance .

I am expecting the website to be properly build as it isn't giving any error in the dev server.